# Which part of code does openssl support AES-NI?

Tags: openssl, aes

I have taken a look at source codes of openssl in C to try to implement aes-ctr encryption on top of my  application.

Also I found that openssl supports AES-NI.
This means that any encryption function provided by openssl (specifically in **aes.h** ) support AES-NI?

Which part of openssl codes support AES-NI?

Comment: is not AES-NI is a CPU specific CPU? and i believe, if its using low level instruction, instead of using C++ it will be backed by [ASM](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/crypto/aes/asm) codes.

Comment: Look in [`<openssl dir>/crypto/aes/asm/`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/crypto/aes/asm) directory. In particular, see `aesni-x86.pl` and `aesni-x86_64.pl`. The `pl` files are templates that get converted into asm source files that the native assembler can consume, and then that is the source file assembled.

Comment: I found em, thanks :-)